# Output list of list in R

Tags: r, list, output, regression, montecarlo

### Explanations of the Goals:

Could someone please help me on this:
I trying to make a Monte Carlo study on the estimators of the Linear Regression beta0hat, beta1hat, R2, R2Adjusted and P-value changing the samples size(30,60,100) and the variance(0.5,0.75,1), using normal a random  error.
First i've created 3 samples of each lenght that is relevant for the study which i don´t want to be random.

```
X1 =  sample(0:20,30,T)
X2 =  sample(0:20,60,T)
X3 = sample(0:20,100,T)
```

For the main purpose, i've created this function of Monte Carlo in witch i´m trying to keep the results of each estimator in some approprieated vectors to generate histograms and a plot of P-value in Y axis against R2 in X axis to verify the behavior of the estimator whem i change the variables and set normal random to the errors.

Arguments of the function:
n = sample size, sig = changed variance, b0 = real betahat0, b1 = real betahat1, X = samples of X axis

```
Monte.Carlo = function(n, sig, b0, b1,X){
      Y = b0 + b1 * X + rnorm(n,0,sig)
      smr = summary(lm(Y~X))
      return(smr)
}
```

To generate the vector that will be my data in this study to analise the behavior of the estimators, i've used the function replicate like this:

```
object.1 = replicate(1000,Monte.Carlo(30,0.5,1.4,0.8,1,X1))
beta0_s0.5_n30 <-list(c(object.1[,1:1000][[4]] [1]))
beta1_s0.5_n30<- object.1[[4]] [2]
R2_s0.5_n30 <- object.1[[8]]
R2A_s0.5_n30 <- object.1[[9]]
valorP_s0.5_n30 <- object.1[[4]] [8]
```

But there is something wrong in this generations above that i can' figured out.

The object.1 seens to have stored 1000 summarys of the regression.

How can i access the 1000 outputs of each estimator of the regression summary and store then in the apropriated vectors, like list of list, as a intented in the comand lines above?

The puspose is to apply this on several objects like in the example below where  i've had changed the variance to 0.75 and the sample size to 60:

```
beta0_s0.75_n60 <- replicate(1000,Monte.Carlo(60,0.75,1.4,0.8,X2))
beta1_s0.75_n60<- replicate(1000,Monte.Carlo(60,0.75,1.4,0.8,X2))
R2_s0.75_n60 <- replicate(1000,Monte.Carlo(60,0.75,1.4,0.8,X2))
R2A_s0.75_n60 <- replicate(1000,Monte.Carlo(60,0.75,1.4,0.8,X2))
valorP_s0.75_n60 <- replicate(1000,Monte.Carlo(60,0.75,1.4,0.8,X2))
```

The final go is to generate 120 graphs like in this example to compare the results:

```
hist(R2A_s0.5_n30,breaks=11)
hist(R2A_s0.75_n30,breaks=11)
hist(R2A_s1_n30,breaks=11)
hist(R2A_s0.5_n60,breaks=11)
hist(R2A_s0.75_n60,breaks=11)
hist(R2A_s1_n60,breaks=11)
hist(R2A_s0.5_n100,breaks=11)
hist(R2A_s0.75_n100,breaks=11)
hist(R2A_s1_n100,breaks=11)
```

I will really appreciate if someone could help on this, i've tryed a lot of solutions and look in some forums and it doesn't make any difference at all.

Sorry about my english grammar errors.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your code doesn't work @Drope. The `object.1 = replicate(1000,Monte.Carlo(30,0.5,1.4,0.8,1,X1))` line has six arguments in the `Monte.Carlo` function whereas the original function has only five.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just assumed that your original `object.1` call was supposed to have only five arguments like the `Monte.Carlo` function itself, and shortened this to:

```
object.1 = replicate(1000,Monte.Carlo(30,0.5,1.4,0.8,X1))
```

Then I made a dummy dataframe (which is a list of lists) with the column names being the statistics you specified

```
o1 <- data.frame(b0 = 0, b1 = 0, R2 = 0, R2A = 0, vP = 0)
```

Then created a for-loop...

```
for (r in 1:length(object.1)) {
         o1[r,"b0"]  <- object.1[4,r][[1]][1,1]
         o1[r,"b1"]  <- object.1[4,r][[1]][2,1]
         o1[r,"R2"]  <- object.1[8,r]
         o1[r,"R2A"] <- object.1[8,r]
         o1[r,"vP"]  <- object.1[4,r][[1]][2,4]
}
```

...where a new row is added to `o1` for every replication of your `Monte.Carlo` function and the relevant statistics extracted via the subsetting functions - `[[]]` and `[,]` - from the each of the one thousand `summary(lm(Y~X))` objects created in `object.1`. `o1` is a dataframe, with each column being a vector of 1000 of each statistic. Apply the same principle for object.2, object.3 etc.

p.s. run the for-loop and you get an error message saying `Error in object.1[4, r] : subscript out of bounds` but then open `o1` and you'll see the loop worked perfectly (I even checked the individual statistics for each replication and they match, so, don't really understand that one :)

Comment: Did that help @Drope?

Comment: Hi llewmills, sorry about the long time to get you the feedback. In fact it helps a lot to guide me to another sollution or way to approch the problem. The code that you made works well but whem i play it on rmarkdown, the error "out of bounds" block the knirt to word doc. I 've tryed a lot of adjustments to fix this but doesn't work. Instead, I made a function that return only the 1000 subsettings that a need in a list just like your data.frame, and works perfectly. Anyway thanks for enlightening the way for me.

Comment: Hi @Drope. Yes I'm a little mystified why it generates an error when it clearly works. A way around it would be to run the for-loop in a regular R script then source that script and call the dataframe (i.e. `o1` in this case)  in rmarkdown. But I'm glad you found a way around your problem. Might ask the boards why this error happens and an alternative means of achieving the same thing, because it's a useful thing to be able to do.